# JAVA.Usage of lambda to make code clean

Tags: java, lambda

Below is my code, in which i use to sort a list of persons depending on the argument.. name or number or emailaddress.
I would like to ask how i could use lambda to beautify this set of code as for all 3 cases, they follow similar logic.

```
if (sortType.equals(NAME)) {
    Collections.sort(ListofPeople, (Person p1, Person p2) ->
            p1.getName().toString().compareTo(p2.getName().toString()));
} else if (sortType.equals(NUMBER)) {
    Collections.sort(ListofPeople, (Person p1, Person p2) ->
            p1.getPhone().toString().compareTo(p2.getPhone().toString()));
} else if (sortType.equals(EMAIL)) {
    Collections.sort(ListofPeople, (Person p1, Person p2) ->
            p1.getPhone().toString().compareTo(p2.getPhone().toString()));
}
```

Comment: Consider first using indentation to make your presented code clean and easily readable.

Comment: I've formatted your code for you this time, but in the future, please consider doing this yourself as this small effort makes your code much easier to understand and is much appreciated by the volunteers who answer questions on this site.

Comment: You simply need a `Map<SortTypeType, Comparator<Person>>`. You can make the lambdas neater by using `Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getName().toString())` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first thing is to use `Comparator.comparing` to get the `Comparator` instances.

For example:

```
Collections.sort(ListofPeople,Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
```

Then, you can use a `Map` to store the various `Comparator`s, and get rid of your if-else statements.

You entire snippet (beside the initialization of the map) will become:

```
Collections.sort(ListofPeople,comparatorMap.get(sortType));
```

Instead of converting the properties you are comparing to `String`s, I'd make sure the types of these properties (phone number, email address, etc...) implement `Comparable`.

Comment: Nit: the entire snippet isn't quite that: you'd need to use `getOrDefault(sortType, (a,b) -> 0)` to handle the no-op "not equal to any of them" case.

Comment: @AndyTurner If the types mentioned in the question are all the possible types, I'm not sure there's a need for a default handler.